# What is a Counting Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a phrase conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Counting Phrase™**.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Counting Phrases™ | Not Counting Phrases™ |
| --- | --- |
| RUSH IN | GET OUT |
| IRON MILL | SMELTING FURNACE |
| LONG GAME | DECISIVE VICTORY |
| IDLE POWER | INCREMENTAL GAME |
| LANE ORDER | FREE PLAY |
| VAPOR BATH | HOT SAUNA |
| EAGLE COIN | DOLLAR BUCKS |
| FLINT CLAY | IRON PICKAXE |
| JAY INSLEE | BILL HASLAM |
| WICKET DOOR | BAFFLE GATE |
| COMMON BENT | FAIRWAY TURF |
| MICHAEL BAY | MICHAEL FOX |
| GRAND COULEE | THREE GORGES |
| OKCUPID LOVE | TINDER MATCH |
| WARRIOR KING | PHILOSOPHER QUEENS |
| COMMUNITY PARK | INDUSTRIAL PARK |
| MOUNTAIN CEDAR | OLIVE GARDEN |
| VALENCIA ORANGE | BLOOD ORANGE |
| TEXAS MOTORPLEX | KENTUCKY SPEEDWAY |
| IMPERIAL CAPITAL | TOWN CENTRE |
| ALTITUDE CHAMBERS | HYPERBOLIC TIME |
| FOUNTAIN INKSTAND | BALL POINT |
| CHRISTIAN MORALITY | RELIGIOUS FUNDAMENTALISM |
| PARTICULATE CARBON | OZONE LAYER |
| SCULPTURESQUE JASPER | TEXTURELESS LIMESTONE |
| SWITZERLAND INTERNATIONAL | NEUTRAL PARTY |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Counting Phrases™,Not Counting Phrases™
RUSH IN,GET OUT
IRON MILL,SMELTING FURNACE
LONG GAME,DECISIVE VICTORY
IDLE POWER,INCREMENTAL GAME
LANE ORDER,FREE PLAY
VAPOR BATH,HOT SAUNA
EAGLE COIN,DOLLAR BUCKS
FLINT CLAY,IRON PICKAXE
JAY INSLEE,BILL HASLAM
WICKET DOOR,BAFFLE GATE
COMMON BENT,FAIRWAY TURF
MICHAEL BAY,MICHAEL FOX
GRAND COULEE,THREE GORGES
OKCUPID LOVE,TINDER MATCH
WARRIOR KING,PHILOSOPHER QUEENS
COMMUNITY PARK,INDUSTRIAL PARK
MOUNTAIN CEDAR,OLIVE GARDEN
VALENCIA ORANGE,BLOOD ORANGE
TEXAS MOTORPLEX,KENTUCKY SPEEDWAY
IMPERIAL CAPITAL,TOWN CENTRE
ALTITUDE CHAMBERS,HYPERBOLIC TIME
FOUNTAIN INKSTAND,BALL POINT
CHRISTIAN MORALITY,RELIGIOUS FUNDAMENTALISM
PARTICULATE CARBON,OZONE LAYER
SCULPTURESQUE JASPER,TEXTURELESS LIMESTONE
SWITZERLAND INTERNATIONAL,NEUTRAL PARTY
```

Helpful changes: Added some more phrases in response to comment expressing character underrepresentation. Added knowledge tag

Hint 1:

> There are two separate, but related, conditions.

Hint 2:

> gnovice has one of the conditions partially figured out; the other condition is alluded to by the category name. As the tag suggests, you may want to search stuff up to confirm your findings.

Comment: Well, I added the phrases visibly to the post, so I felt hint 1 was fair to reveal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding onto @gnovice's answer, the phrases must meet the following conditions:

> One of the words must contain a two-letter abbreviation of a state.
> The other word is a county in that state.

Listed out:

> ```
> RUSH IN                   = Rush County, Indiana
> IRON MILL                 = Iron County, Michigan
> LONG GAME                 = Long County, Georgia
> IDLE POWER                = Power County, Idaho
> LANE ORDER                = Lane County, Oregon
> VAPOR BATH                = Bath County, Virginia
> EAGLE COIN                = Eagle County, Colorado
> FLINT CLAY                = Clay County, Florida
> JAY INSLEE                = Jay County, Indiana
> WICKET DOOR               = Door County, Wisconsin
> COMMON BENT               = Bent County, Colorado
> MICHAEL BAY               = Bay County, Michigan
> GRAND COULEE              = Grand County, Colorado
> OKCUPID LOVE              = Love County, Oklahoma
> WARRIOR KING              = King County, Washington
> COMMUNITY PARK            = Park County, Colorado
> MOUNTAIN CEDAR            = Cedar County, Missouri
> VALENCIA ORANGE           = Orange County, Virginia
> TEXAS MOTORPLEX           = Texas County, Missouri
> IMPERIAL CAPITAL          = Imperial County, California
> ALTITUDE CHAMBERS         = Chambers County, Alabama
> FOUNTAIN INKSTAND         = Fountain County, Indiana
> CHRISTIAN MORALITY        = Christian County, Missouri
> PARTICULATE CARBON        = Carbon County, Pennsylvania
> SCULPTURESQUE JASPER      = Jasper County, South Carolina
> SWITZERLAND INTERNATIONAL = Switzerland County, Indiana
> ```

Comment: You both contributed to the final answer. Would you mind if I give the bounty reward to @gnovice, since you got the green checkmark points?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I'm all for giving credit where it's due!  It's your bounty, so please distribute the reward as you see fit.  I like the minty checkmarks better, anyway.  =)

Answer (score 6):

### Partial answer

I'm fairly certain that one of the two conditions involves...

> ...having at least one word that starts with the [two-letter abbreviation for a state](https://www.infoplease.com/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes). All of the Counting Phrases™ satisfy that, but only a few of the Non-Counting Phrases™ do:
>
> ```
> RUSH IN                      GET OUT
> IRON MILL                    SMELTING FURNACE
> LONG GAME                    DECISIVE VICTORY
> IDLE POWER                   INCREMENTAL GAME
> LANE ORDER                   FREE PLAY
> VAPOR BATH                   HOT SAUNA
> EAGLE COIN                   DOLLAR BUCKS
> FLINT CLAY                   IRON PICKAXE
> JAY INSLEE                   BILL HASLAM
> WICKET DOOR                  BAFFLE GATE
> COMMON BENT                  FAIRWAY TURF
> MICHAEL BAY                  MICHAEL FOX
> GRAND COULEE                 THREE GORGES
> OKCUPID LOVE                 TINDER MATCH
> WARRIOR KING                 PHILOSOPHER QUEENS
> COMMUNITY PARK               INDUSTRIAL PARK
> MOUNTAIN CEDAR               OLIVE GARDEN
> VALENCIA ORANGE              BLOOD ORANGE
> TEXAS MOTORPLEX              KENTUCKY SPEEDWAY
> IMPERIAL CAPITAL             TOWN CENTRE
> ALTITUDE CHAMBERS            HYPERBOLIC TIME
> FOUNTAIN INKSTAND            BALL POINT
> CHRISTIAN MORALITY           RELIGIOUS FUNDAMENTALISM
> PARTICULATE CARBON           OZONE LAYER
> SCULPTURESQUE JASPER         TEXTURELESS LIMESTONE
> SWITZERLAND INTERNATIONAL    NEUTRAL PARTY
> ```
>
> I think one of the most helpful entries will be `MICHAEL BAY` versus `MICHAEL FOX`, but I haven't figured out the second condition yet.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely on the right track (although the other condition will help explain why)